# Uninstall Composer while keeping dependancies

Tags: php, composer-php

I was wondering if it is possible to use Composer to install dependencies for a script and then uninstall composer, as it is known to be a big RAM hogger.
Would this work?
Thanks

Comment: When composer finishes installing project dependencies, it stops running. Then yes you can uninstall it, won't affect your project anyway, but it won't solve your RAM hogger problem.

Comment: Hmm okay, so the installed dependencies will still remain after I uninstall composer? Also, I was referring to Composer when saying it uses lots of RAM.

Comment: Composer use the ram only when is running, when if finished the task it terminates himself, so it doesn't eat RAM anymore. There is no point to uninstall it as it never run in background, only if you launch it. Even, if you launch composer and you close the terminal window, it will be terminated.

Comment: I know what are referring to. composer download the dependencies and generate autoload script and put them to the project folder, then it finishes its job and terminates, it doesn't run in the background after that. The RAM hogging problem could be related to your development environment setting.

Answer (score 0):

Once the Composer has downloaded the dependencies, it has nothing to do with the them. They remain in your local directory.

I have not personally experienced the RAM hogging of composer. So no idea about that. As far as my knowledge is concerned, composer downloads the dependencies and stops working until it gets another command!

You can feel free to uninstall it after you've got all libraries set in place.